# 2 column layout with 100% height but not 100% width

Tags: css, multiple-columns

My Problem is that I need to have two columns same height but not 100% width. The whole thing is centered an has a fullscreen BG-Image.

I found a lot of solutions for the famous 2 column problem for 100% width but not if the width is fixed.

I know the [Matthew James Taylor Solution](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts) but it is just for 100% width layout.

So here is the layout I got from the graphic designer

```
                  -------------------------------------------    
                  |sub menu|           content              |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  |        |                                |
                  ---------|--------------------------------|
                           |          footer                |
                           |--------------------------------|
```

So the sub menu has a fixed width and the content & footer a max-width.

Sometimes the sub menu is higher and sometimes the content area. Anyway they have to be both the same height (with the background).

The closest I got (the position absolute makes the work):

```
#main-holder {
position: relative;
max-width: 944px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
padding-top: 140px;
z-index: 10;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}


#cont-holder{
position: absolute;
display: block;
float: left;
max-width: 676px;
min-height: 100%;
margin-left: 134px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}


#content{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#sub-holder{
position: relative;
background-color: none;
float: left;
width: 134px;
margin-right: -134px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#subs {
background: #000000;
padding:10px;
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
height: 100%;
}
```

and here the HTML

```
<div id="main-holder">
    <div id="sub-holder">
         <div id="subs">
            sub menu
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont-holder">
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

works perfect when the sub menu is longer then the content. but if the sub menu is shorter than it cuts off from the content.

happy for any help :-)

Comment: So to answer my question myself....

I couldn't find a css solution which will fit....and time is running....

jQuery had to help me out:
http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/equal-column-height-with-jquery/

works perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

You want some table-like layout:

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.row > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="subs">subs</div>
        <div id="main">main</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AWJph/

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good reference for you to check out.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm